# Does a chain of classical harmonic oscillators exhibit non-harmonic oscillations?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, coupled-oscillators, anharmonic-oscillators

Consider a one dimensional chain of N classical point masses interacting with neighbor harmonic forces. Is it possible to find initial conditions (positions and velocities) such that non-periodic (irregular) oscillations can be observed ? If yes, what is the relative size phase space that leads to this ? i.e how likely is to observe this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An infinite chain has infinitely many frequencies, so almost any initial condition will lead to non-periodic motions. Even  finite, length $N$  chain will have frequencies such as
$$
\omega_n \propto \cos (2\pi n/N)
$$
and these will have irrational ratios, and so again almost any initial condition will lead to non-periodic motion.

For example the equations for masses in the middle of the chain have the form
$$
\ddot \eta_n=\lambda(\eta_{n+1} +\eta_{n-1}-2\eta_n),
$$

These have solutions in the form of complex traveling waves
$$
\eta_n=e^{ikn-i\omega t},
$$
where
$$
\omega^2=2\lambda(1-\cos k) =4 \lambda \sin^2 (k/2), 
$$
so
$$
\omega= 2\lambda \sin (k/2).
$$
The boundary conditions determine the allowed $k$.

Comment: Where does your expression for the frequency come from ?

Comment: You just solve the harmonic  chain. Have you tried this?  It is a standard problem in "small oscillations" There could be sine instead of a cosine, it depends on the boundary conditions at the ends of the chain.

Comment: I guess you refer to the dispersion of the linear chain and you simplified the mass and the bonding constants. So your argument is that all the frequencies present in the dispersion relation will superpose to non-periodic oscillations ?

Comment: It's only when two  excited frequencies have rational ratios that the motion due to the two modes can be periodic.

Comment: Another question : In the derivation of this dispersion one assumes cosine or sine time-dependence. But is this really the most general solution ?

Comment: Also if these different modes have different energies, then one can find configurations with only few modes (and hence effectively periodic) by decreasing the energy of the chain, what do you think ?

Comment: Cosine or Sine: is that all that is needed?  This   goes back to arguments between Daniel Bernoulli (yes) and d'Alembert and Euler (no) in the 1700's. Fourier settled it in 1807.: yes all motion can be decomposed in harmonic motion.

Comment: Even two modes, one with frequency $\omega$ and one with frequency $\sqrt{2} \omega$, will never get back in phase